# Host ASP.NET site at specific endpoint

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, asp.net

In short i would like to host an ASP.NET MVC 5 application at a specific endpoint.

I have an application server AS01, and our domain controller DC01 (DNS server as well).
The ASP.NET site is running on IIS on the application server port 80.
I would like this site to be accessible at something like: http://intranet/mysite
within our company network.

I know that i somehow need to set up some DNS entries to make it reachable at **intranet**.
But how do i achieve that it is reachable not under http://intranet but http://intranet/**mysite**.

This might sound like a silly question, but i dont even know where to start looking.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Like you found out, DNS can only help you resolve the `intranet` part. If you want to manipulate the URL further like the `mysite` part, you need to configure reverse proxy rules (either on this IIS with ARR, or use another reverse proxy server). You can learn more from a search engine, as such topics have been extensively discussed for decades.

Comment: Thank you that will be it. I will research more into that